# How to install tensorflow 1.15.0 in Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server

I am using Azure to create an Ubuntu server 18.04. The python3 default version in this VM is `3.6.9`. I tried to install python3-pip, then install Tensorflow version 1.15.0 by command: `sudo pip3 install Tensorflow==1.15.0`.

However I got this error: `No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15.0`

I really don't know how to fix it. On my Windows PC, I got the same error while using python3.7, then I change to use python3.6.5 and everythings is fine. So that I think maybe I should try to install python 3.6.5 on Ubuntu VM. But again, this time, I can't install correctly python 3.6.5 on my Ubuntu server.

Can you please help me to fix it. I am just a newbie and honestly, I am not really good with Ubuntu.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. 
A simple upgrade of pip to the latest version by:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip
```

solved the problem for me. Checkout https://askubuntu.com/questions/712339/how-to-upgrade-pip-to-latest for details how to upgrade pip.

After checking it seems the pip3 version shipped with Ubuntu defaults to pip 9.0.1. However, this version seems to supports only up to Tensorflow 1.14.

I would also strongly suggest to use virtual environments like Anaconda in order not to mess up your system python. 
E.g.: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

Answer (score 3):

These are the [list](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.15.0/#files) of files for TensorFlow 1.15

This command would work:

```
pip3 install tensorflow==1.15.0
```

I do see the manylinux wheel file for Ubuntu.

What CPU model and pip version are you using?

Debugging:

```
pip3 -v install tensorflow==1.15.0 | grep Found | more
```

Can help you see which platform and tags `pip3` is trying to find in wheel files.

In the past I also have seen issue with pip default version (9.0.1), make sure you are running a recent version (e.g. pip-20.0.2):

```
apt install python3-pip  && pip3 install --upgrade pip
```